# How can header value can be read from a file and pass in CURL request?

Tags: curl

How can header value can be read from a file and pass in CURL request ?

My CURL request is:

```
curl -H "X-Auth-Token: <token>" http://a.b.c.d:9696/v2.0/subnets
```

The  here is of more than 1000 characters.

Is there a way that 'token' can be stored in a file and then that can be directly used in curl request?

I tried using '-K' and '-d' but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same need, I've done it this way :

```
> curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat jwt.txt)" https://myserver/myrequest
```

'jwt.txt' is the file with my JWT token.

Answer (score 0):

No direct way to do this, I'd suggest `cat your file | xargs curl` or write a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
auth=`cat your_file`
arg="-H \"X-Auth-Token:$auth\""
curl $arg your_URL
```